# O que é o buffer overflow?

Tags: c, funções, segurança, memória

Sempre que uso a função `gets()` o compilador me retorna o seguinte aviso:

> function is dangerous and should not be used

Tradução:

> esta função é perigosa e não deveria ser usada

Ouço muito falar que ela é perigosa e que no lugar dela deve ser usada a função `fgets()` para evitar o tal do *buffer overflow*.

Afinal de contas, o que seria o *buffer overflow* e que tipo de perigo ele representaria para o meu software? E o que faz a função `gets()` ser vulnerável ao *buffer overflow*? Além da função `gets()` existe outras que sejam vulneráveis ao *buffer overflow*?

Comment: O [artigo da wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) me parece bem completo. (A versão em português também tem bastante conteúdo se você preferir)

Comment: Mas eu prefiro que a resposta esteja aqui, rsrs.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Se usou uma vez, viu o aviso e continuou usando, está cometendo um erro.

## Buffer overflow

A função `gets()` recebe uma variável que funciona como um *buffer*. Ou seja, uma variável é criada e passada para a função que colocará um valor nela. Quando a variável é criada ela tem um tamanho específico. Essa função não tem nenhuma medida para garantir que o valor não ultrapasse o tamanho da variável. A linguagem C por si só não possui mecanismos que garantem o limite do tamanho do objeto contido na variável.

O estouro do *buffer* ocorre quando o valor obtido (na leitura do dispositivo) é maior que o tamanho reservado para a variável. Então a função escreve em uma área que está reservada para outra coisa. Podendo escrever onde não deve ela permite que a execução seja adulterada e o código acabe fazendo algo inesperado, abrindo brechas de segurança.

Os "hackers" se aproveitam desta falha para enviar dados que eles sabem que vão sobrescrever memória de forma indevida. Entendendo as posições de memória que a aplicação estará usando em determinada situação ele pode mandar um código ou modificar um dado que executará um código indevido que não faz parte do funcionamento esperado na aplicação, como por exemplo habilitando um *login* mesmo sem uma senha correta.

## Solução

A grande vantagem da função `fgets()` e [outras semelhantes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42981/101) é que um de seus parâmetros diz o tamanho do *buffer* e a função garante que não ultrapassará esse limite, mesmo que o valor que ela esteja recebendo seja maior. Desta forma o dado não pode interferir em outras áreas da memória.

## Outras funções perigosas

Cuidado também com (segue a alternativa "segura" já existente no padrão):

- `strcpy()` -> `strncpy()`
- `strcat()` -> `strncat()`
- `strlen()` -> `strnlen()`
- `strcmp()` -> `strncmp()`
- `strdup()` -> `strndup()`
- `wcscpy()` -> `wcsncpy()`
- `wcslen()` -> `wcsnlen()`
- `sprintf()` -> `snprintf()`

Outras que podem ser ruins em algumas situações: - `scanf()`, `getwd()`, `realpath()` `atoi()`, `memcpy()`, `strtok()`,

Algumas dessas funções possuem variações perigosas também. Note que a alternativa não é garantidamente segura, elas apenas possuem um mecanismo um pouco melhor, elas não substituem o uso correto delas e verificações adicionais.

Algumas são perigosas e propensa a estouro de *buffer* apenas se mal usadas. A `gets()` realmente é perigosa não importando o que o programador faça.

Obviamente não arrisco dizer que esta é uma lista completa.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: A [`strncpy()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.2.4) não é uma alternativa segura para [`strcpy()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.2.3). Elas têm funcionalidades diferentes.

Comment: @pmg por exemplo?

Comment: `char s100[100]; strncpy(s100, "", 100);` vai encher `s100` de `'\0'`; `strcpy(s100, "");` vai apenas escrever um byte. Também pode acontecer que o resultado final de `strncpy()` não inclua o terminador.

Comment: @pmg e qual será a alternativa então?

Comment: A alternativa é passar os tamanhos dos arrays sempre que necessário; e validar sempre antes de fazer algo "perigoso".

Comment: @pmg como passar o tamanho em `strcpy()`?

Comment: Deves fazer a validação **antes** de chamar `strcpy()`.

Comment: É que você falou em passar e a função não permite. Ficou claro agora, vou editar para melhorar essa parte.

Answer (score 6):

**O que é Buffer Overflow?**

Olha cara o Buffer Overflow em português quer dizer "Estouro de Buffer" é quando algo excede o limite, por exemplo se você tem um array que só pode receber 10 valores e você coloca nesse array 11 valores Pronto isso é buffer overflow porque houve um estouro de memória(ultrapassou o tamanho limite).

**Que tipo de perigo ele representaria para o meu software?**

Um perigo muito grande, a maioria dos exploits são feitos baseados nessa falha de buffer overflow sendo assim o atacante ao identifica uma falha de buffer overflow em seu software ele pode injetar diversos códigos maliciosos no seu software e fazer estragos, burlar proteções do seu software caso seja um soft pago OU se o seu software for um soft remoto(conexão internet) imagina o estrago o atacante conseguindo invadir várias pessoas por meio da falha causada no seu software.

**Por que a função gets() é vulnerável a Buffer Overflow??**

A explicação mais simples para essa pergunta é o seguinte: Essa função não limita o número de caracteres a serem lidos da entrada padrão (stdin).

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 4):

Buffer overflow é quando de alguma maneira é inserido mais dados de entrada do que esperado pelo seu programa,  isso causa um estouro de memória comprometendo a execução do programa, isso permite sobrescrever a memória que permite utilizar de endereços para execução de códigos arbitrarios pelo SO.

A função fgets até onde sei não possui nenhuma checagem na prevenção quanto ao tamanho de strings passado para o seu programa, isso quer dizer que se você define uma variável de tamanho 200 e um usuário/hacker tentar inserir 250 valores, o seu programa vai estar estourando o buffer desta variável permitindo sobrescrever a memória do seu SO.

Além do fgets o strcpy tbm pode sofrer do mesmo mal, na verdade qualquer função que permita  entrada de dados sem verificações.

Em alguns SO's (Linux) o kernel integra técnicas de ASLR (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), na tentativa de previnir estes problemas junto ao compilador.

Aqui já rolou algo prático sobre este tipo de exploração, se tiver interesse leia este post:

[Segurança - Syscall dentro de shellcode não executa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76571/seguran%c3%a7a-syscall-dentro-de-shellcode-n%c3%a3o-executa/77490#77490)

Answer (score 3):

Sendo o buffer o espaço que cada variável tem num programa, esse espaço é limitado. Por exemplo cada char, normalmente, é um byte.

Buffer overflow significa escrever para além do espaço da variável alterando posições seguintes de memória. Isto tem vários problemas: undefined behaviour, crashes ou até exploits. Um hacker pode controlar o seu programa. Um dos casos mais notórios é nos jogos de PSP alterando o nome dos savefiles para strings muito grandes, para além do permitido pelo jogo causava crashes em que os hackers tomavam controlo e executavam o seu código.Não vou aprofundar muito pois sou um novato e espero não cometer erros.

A função gets é perigosa, porque o utilizador é que escolhe quantos caracteres introduz. Se a string apenas tiver 30 e o utilizador inserir 31 há buffer overflow, pois a string vai sendo armazenada e vai ocupar mais 1 byte adjacente que não pertence string.

Sim há mais. De momento só me lembro do scanf, em situações normais o compilador avisa por isso não é necessário saber de cor.