# Existem linguagens mais seguras que outras?

Tags: segurança, independente-de-linguagem

Algumas linguagens são mais seguras que outras? Ou isso não depende da linguagem e sim do programador?

**A linguagem em que um programa é programado, interfere na segurança do mesmo, independente do programador?**

Comment: Linguagens de alto nível costumam ser mais seguras tanto para o desenvolvedor devido aos Garbage Collectors e outras facilidades para evitar travamentos, leaks e exceções da aplicação, entre outras vantagens, quanto seguras para os usuários que vão passar por camadas adicionais de segurança. As linguagens do .Net framework são um bom exemplo...

Comment: Resposta puramente teórica: não, pois se uma linguagem [turing-completa](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completude) `A` fosse de alguma forma "menos segura" que outra linguagem `B`, bastaria você escrever em `A` um interpretador para `B` e então programar em `B`, para atingir um nível de "segurança" similar. Portanto, toda linguagem [turing-completa] é igualmente "segura". (Nota: estou intencionalmente evitando definir o que "segurança" significa, já que esse é um tópico bastante contextual, não dá pra responder no abstrato sem a resposta ficar ampla demais)

Comment: @mgibsonbr excelente "resposta" :) Confirmando o que eu disse com muito mais propriedade e concisão :P

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Linguagens de programação não são inerentemente seguras ou inseguras, elas são um meio de expressão. Quem tem que fazer algo seguro é o programador.

Algumas evitam certos tipos de problemas que causam mais inseguranças, outras facilitam o erro. Algumas linguagens podem usar bibliotecas que podem ter falhas de segurança, mas isto é raro. Especialmente é raro ter a falha ali dentro. O que é mais comum é a pessoa fazer uso errado daquilo que tem um potencial danoso. [Biblioteca](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/101) não é a [linguagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101). Nem mesmo a [implementação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111284/101) dela, é no máximo a implementação de um complemento que é especificado que a linguagem deve ter.

Por exemplo, C tem funções na biblioteca padrão que claramente podem explorar um [*buffer overflow*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115613/101). Isto por si só não é um problema de segurança, a maneira como se usa uma função assim é que é inseguro. Em última análise é inseguro usá-la, mas não que ela seja insegura. Tem como usá-la sem incorrer em problemas de segurança.

PHP, só pra citar um exemplo, tá cheio de funções inseguras para uso. Não que elas causem problemas de segurança, pelo menos não a maioria, mas o programador tem dificuldade de usá-las de um jeito seguro. Elas incentivam a insegurança. Mas se souber o que está fazendo, pode usar. Incluindo as funções `mysql_*` que são consideradas obsoletas.

Então é claro que a linguagem pode interferir na segurança de forma indireta, ela só não é determinante.

Claro que pode ter alguma linguagem específica, provavelmente não *mainstream*, que possa ter um problema próprio de segurança, mas aí beira a piada. É óbvio que, hipoteticamente, alguém pode criar uma linguagem que você escreve um `if` e ela abre uma porta para um *hacker* entrar possivelmente como administrador. Ainda assim é problema do programador que fez a linguagem e provavelmente de quem escolheu usá-la.

O que pode ter mais em uma linguagem é a implementação dela (o compilador) gerar um problema de segurança, mas mesmo assim cai no que eu disse antes. Isso provavelmente é algo transitório. Você não verá na especificação de uma linguagem séria que ela deva fazer algo inseguro.

Não estamos falando de segurança de tipos e outras coisas do tipo.

Para entender bem isso é preciso entender [O que caracteriza uma linguagem de programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102452/101) e até [Como é desenvolvida uma linguagem de programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124436/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Quanto ao último parágrafo, é interessante separar _linguagem_ de _implementação da linguagem_. Os problemas de segurança geralmente estão na implementação.

Comment: O PHP tem algumas funções inseguras para manter compatibilidade vide as `mysql_*` ;) haha.

Comment: @PabloAlmeida adicionado, obrigado.

Comment: @rray mas aí é biblioteca e mesmo assim, não tem insegurança alguma nessas função. Zero. O jeito que as pessoas usam isto é que costuma ser inseguro. Mas dá pra usá-las sem risco.

Comment: ótima explicação @bigown , agradeço e acredito que vai servir de ajuda para muitos aqui do Stack

Answer (score 7):

Em contraste com a resposta do Maniero eu digo que linguagens são sim inerentemente seguras ou inseguras em seu contexto de uso (digamos OS *programming* ou web *programming*) e elas são um dos fatores determinantes na segurança da sua aplicação. Essa mentalidade muito focada em que "o programador tem que saber fazer direito", que "ele é o responsável" é  um atraso de vida. O programador é humano e ele é falho, ele pode e eventualmente vai errar, a não ser que a linguagem que ele use para expressar seus programas não permita que ele cometa o erro.

Veja por exemplo como você tem toneladas de brechas de seguranças sempre surgindo em sistemas operacionais e navegadores, sendo estes geralmente escritos em C/C++, devido a coisas simples como escrever dados fora dos limites alocados de um array. Você pode dizer que foram os desenvolvedores que fizeram errado, que a culpa da insegurança é deles e blá, mas no fim isso não muda o fato de que desenvolver algo como um sistema operacional em C ou C++ é inseguro, a linguagem vai possibilitar a existência de certas brechas de segurança e inevitavelmente estas vão aparecer no código, sendo que isso poderia ser evitado pela própria linguagem. Veja por exemplo [Rust](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rust_(linguagem_de_programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)), uma linguagem de baixo nível desenvolvida pela mozilla; uma das principais razões de sua criação foi justamente a segurança, em Rust você elimina uma multitude de brechas de segurança relacionadas a memória, sendo que tais brechas são comuns em código C/C++, e a própria linguagem resolve este problema por ser segura em manipulação de memória.

Um outro exemplo de nível mais alto é a programação web, pense no problema de segurança clássico desse contexto, SQL injection. É um mandamento divino de programação web que você deve escapar seus dados antes de jogar eles em *queries* que são enviadas para a *database* (ou usar *prepared statements*), contudo não é difícil ver pessoas postando códigos que não fazem isso aqui mesmo no *stack oveflow*. Isso é culpa da falta de conhecimento (ou desleixo) do programador, mas seria da linguagem também? sim. Nada impede que você projete uma linguagem web em que seja impossível passar dados não escapados para *queries* de *database*, e então pronto, você tem uma linguagem que é segura contra SQL injection, o problema não existe mais independentemente da ação do programador.

Então para finalizar: nem todos os problemas de segurança são afetados pela linguagem usada, você colocar a senha do seu servidor em um código  que o usuário pode inspecionar vai ser inseguro em qualquer linguagem do universo, contudo de modo geral a linguagem em que você desenvolve um software interfere diretamente na segurança do mesmo, independentemente do programador.

Comment: Parece que alguém deu downvote nas duas respostas, fiquei curioso sobre o terceiro ponto de vista.

Comment: Provavelmente foi a mesma pessoa que deu downvote na pergunta... Eu gostei da pergunta (e de ambas as respostas), mas confesso que achei ela um tantinho ampla demais, até tentei dar minha própria resposta mas não consegui rsrs!

Comment: @BrunoRB ótima complementação, bem detalhado, obrigado por compartilhar seu conhecimento com todos nós

Answer (score -1):

"As duas coisas".

Se a linguagem expõe determinadas coisas ao ataque, como a possibilidade de null pointers serem referenciados e darem segfaults, então a linguagem é insegura. Ela até mesmo exige que você se policie para não cair nessa brecha!

É como viver numa casa. O portão é talvez a parte menos segura, e você sempre terá que prestar mais atenção nele: se nunca se esquecer de mantê-lo trancado, usar um bom cadeado e só abrir quando for atravessá-lo, bem, sem problemas! Mas, se você usar um cadeado ruim, ou em um descuido esquecer de trancar, bem, torça para que os ladrões não reparem!

Ou quem sabe você não delega os cuidados desse portão a terceiros, como em um condomínio fechado? Talvez você esteja interessado nesse *tradeoff*...

Talvez a gente se dê conta disso olhando para certos extremos. Por exemplo, a linguagem assembly inerentemente expõe toda a máquina ao programador e é absurdamente menos segura, ao passo que Python abstrai toda a máquina e é bem mais segura.