# como resolver erro “SIGSEGV” ao usar `strcpy`

Tags: c, c++, ponteiro, gerenciamento-de-memória, posix

Ola,

estou enfrentando um Erro "SIGSEGV"  na seguinte linha:

`strcpy(buffer_ReceiveAutomation,   ls_buffer_PPouAUT);` << ERRO

e

buffer esta vindo incompleto do recv,
mas se eu trocar o `sizeof(ls_buffer_PPouAUT)` pela quantidade de caracteres funciona, por que?

Estou utilizando linguagem C em um sistema Posix, se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço.

Declarações:

```
char
*ls_buffer_PPouAUT,
*buffer_ReceivePinPad,
*buffer_ReceiveAutomation;
```

Iniciações:

```
        //
        //  se ha memoria alocada
        //
        if(ls_buffer_PPouAUT    !=  NULL)
        {
            //
            //  Libera memoria alocada
            //
            free(ls_buffer_PPouAUT);
            ls_buffer_PPouAUT           =   NULL;
        }

        //
        //  Inicializa o buffer que recebera com pacote
        //
        ls_buffer_PPouAUT           =   malloc(5120*sizeof(char));

        if(ls_buffer_PPouAUT    ==  NULL)
        {

            //
            //  Exibe a mensagem
            //
            GEDI_LCD_DrawString(CENTER, APFONT_HEIGHT*20, APFONT_WIDTH, APFONT_HEIGHT, "Erro realocar memoria!");
            GEDI_CLOCK_Delay(1000);

            //
            //  Fecha Thread  Recive
            //
            pthread_detach(pthread_self());
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }

        //ls_buffer_PPouAUT         = "TESTE";

        //
        //  Recebe pacote
        //
        ln_retorno_receive          =   recv
                                        (
                                            in_socket_handler,
                                            ls_buffer_PPouAUT,
                                            sizeof(ls_buffer_PPouAUT),
                                            0
                                        );
        //
        //  Validacao de erros
        //
        if(ln_retorno_receive   <   0)
        {

            //
            //  Exibe a mensagem
            //
            GEDI_LCD_DrawString(CENTER, APFONT_HEIGHT*20, APFONT_WIDTH, APFONT_HEIGHT, "Erro ao receber!");
            GEDI_CLOCK_Delay(1000);

            //
            //  Libera memoria alocada
            //
            free(ls_buffer_PPouAUT);
            ls_buffer_PPouAUT           =   NULL;

            //
            //  Para a transacao
            //
            in_controle_execucao            =   9;
            perror("recv");

            //
            //  Fecha Thread  Recive
            //
            pthread_detach(pthread_self());
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }

        //
        //  Seta o fim do pacote
        //
        ls_buffer_PPouAUT[ln_retorno_receive]           =   '\0';

        GEDI_LCD_DrawString(5, APFONT_HEIGHT*18, APFONT_WIDTH*0.65, APFONT_HEIGHT*0.65,"P1 >%s<                              ", ls_buffer_PPouAUT);
        GEDI_CLOCK_Delay(1000);
```

> Print acima mostra somente os 4 primeiros caracteres da que deveria ser recebido

```
//
//  Se ha memoria alocada
//
if(buffer_ReceiveAutomation !=  NULL)
{

    //
    //  Libera memoria alocada
    //
    free(buffer_ReceiveAutomation);
    buffer_ReceiveAutomation            =   NULL;
}

//
//  Inicializa o buffer que recebera com pacote
//
buffer_ReceiveAutomation            =   malloc(5120*sizeof(char));

if(buffer_ReceiveAutomation ==  NULL)
{

    //
    //  Exibe a mensagem
    //
    GEDI_LCD_DrawString(CENTER, APFONT_HEIGHT*20, APFONT_WIDTH, APFONT_HEIGHT, "AUT - Erro alocar memoria!");
    GEDI_CLOCK_Delay(1000);

    //
    //  Fecha Thread  Recive
    //
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

//
//  Seta buffer Local
//
strcpy(buffer_ReceiveAutomation,    ls_buffer_PPouAUT);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Nota importante:**
>
> Quando você faz:
>
> ```
> ls_buffer_PPouAUT = "TESTE";
> ```
>
> você imediatamente causa um [vazamento de memória](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vazamento_de_mem%C3%B3ria) (*memory leak*).
>   Anteriormente você havia alocado memória usando `malloc` e atribuido o
>   endereço da alocação à essa variável, e nessa linha você simplesmente
>   "joga esse endereço fora" e coloca na variável o endereço alocado pelo
>   compilador para a string fixa `"TESTE"`. Assim, a memória alocada
>   anteriormente está perdida e não pode ser resgatada até que a sua
>   aplicação seja encerrada! Para evitar esse problema, use `strcpy` aqui
>   também!

Eu não consegui identificar o porquê da sua segunda chamada a `strcpy` estar causando erro, já que você está copiando uma área de memória menor (o conteúdo `"TESTE\0"` na variável `ls_buffer_PPouAUT`) para a área maior alocada (com lixo qualquer - se vc estiver executando em *release* - na variável `buffer_ReceiveAutomation`). Se fosse o contrário a explicação seria óbvia: a cópia invadiu o espaço alocado, porque essa função vai copiar bytes até achar a terminação de string (o `\0`).

Por isso a boa prática indica **não usar `strcpy`**, mas sim [`strncpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/?kw=strncpy) (em que você *precisa informar o tamanho máximo* que deve ser cópiado).

De todas as formas, como eu disse, apesar do vazamento de memória não parece haver nada necessariamente errado com a chamada de `strcpy` nesse local. Mas como ela involve o acesso à memória, talvez esse erro seja decorrente de alguma outra operação anterior em que você fez alguma manipulação errada e o erro não aconteceu imediatamente. Alguns compiladores, por exemplo, "limpam" a memória assim que ela é alocada quando você executa em modo debug, mas não fazem isso quando executa em modo release por motivos de melhoria de desempenho (isto é, deixam ao seu cargo tomar esse cuidado!). Aí então certos erros não ficam tão aparentes quando você executa em debug.

> **Por exemplo**: se a sua string de origem (`ls_buffer_PPouAUT`) não
>   tivesse sido inicializada com `"TESTE\0"` e você estivesse executando
>   em modo release, haveria lixo na área alocada pelo `malloc`. A função
>   `strcpy` vai tentar copiar caracteres dessa origem **até achar** um
>   `\0`, que pode demorar muito pra ser achado (já que a área não foi
>   inicializada e só tem lixo). Se demorar mais do que os 5120 bytes
>   alocados no destino, a cópia vai invadir área de memória não alocada (vai ultrapassar o limite máximo do destino),
>   e aí o erro vai certamente ocorrer.

Além disso, [invadir memória](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/115619/73) (isto é, copiar dados *além* da área alocada) pode não ser problemático para certos sistemas operacionais se isso ocorrer dentro do espaço de uso do aplicativo (o que geralmente não é o caso de sistemas *nix). E aí o "erro" também pode demorar a aparecer, produzindo falsas indicações em outros lugares.

Por isso, convém analisar de forma mais ampla no seu código para procurar por outros vazamentos e/ou invasões. E considere mesmo usar o `strncpy` no lugar do outro. :)

Comment: Sim, acho que pode ser isso mesmo, pois debugo remotamente pois esse código esta sendo rodado em uma maquina externa com sistema bem rudimentar, vou fazer um teste apenas executando para ver se passo desse strcpy e, obrigado, vou adotar o uso de strncpy

Comment: Funcionou, troquei por `strncpy`, mas tenho outro problema quando inclui o `recv`, ele esta guardando somente os 4 primeiros caracteres que teria receber

Comment: Desculpe, não entendi o outro problema. O que é "inclui o recv"? Quando vc diz que "está guardando somente os 4 primeiros caracteres", quer dizer guardando onde? Vc tem certeza que recebeu mais do que 4 caracteres (isto é, qual é o tamanho da variável `ln_retorno_receive`?).  De todas as formas, **este site não é um fórum**. Se você tem outro problema, abra outra pergunta (e aproveite as perguntas que eu comentei pra deixar sua pergunta clara).