# Conversão de byte array para string ao compilar revelando a string no código compilado em C

Tags: c, array, string, segurança

Estou utilizando a função abaixo para fazer a conversão do `byte array` para uma `string`, mas ao analisar o código compilado noto que a `string` é mostrada claramente (*utilizando um editor hex*), o que não desejo.

```
char arr_code[] = {79, 99, 117, 108, 116, 97, 100, 111, 32, 110, 111, 32, 99, 195, 179, 100, 105, 103, 111, 32, 99, 111, 109, 112, 105, 108, 97, 100, 111};
char *byte_arr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
memcpy(byte_arr, arr_code, sizeof arr_code);
char *str_code = byte_arr;
```

No caso a `string` do `byte array` é `Ocultado no código compilado` e está exposta no código compilado mesmo não sendo definida claramente no script C, porque isso ocorre?

Como posso fazer para que o código possa ser compilado sem que o *resultado* do `byte array` fique exposto?

Comment: Acho que era importante saber é por que motivo precisa disso, pode nem ser preciso esconder no C.

Comment: A url da api está sendo exposta, o que daria _um pezinho_ para que alguém tentasse buscar mais informações e por fim tentar obter ou fraudar uma comunicação legitima com o servidor. A falsa sensação de segurança já ajuda, já que o código é demasiadamente extenso. @JorgeB.

Comment: `char *byte_arr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));` vai alocar apenas `1` byte

Comment: Já efetuei as mudanças necessárias para evitar isso @pmg obrigado por me dar esse toque.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Está definido claramente no código C. Uma *string* é um *array* de *bytes*, então ela está definida direitinho ali. Ele não só não protege nada, como está errado (a não ser que outro trecho conserte a falta de finalização da *string*). A cópia não está fazendo nada útil a não ser tentar copiar a suposta *string* para outro local da memória (pode causar problema por não ter um terminador. E ainda terá um problema de [*buffer overflow*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115613/101) já que foi alocado apenas 1 *byte* na memória. O resto será alocado em memória não reservada e vai misturar objetos dando uma confusão danada.

Estes códigos geram exatamente o mesmo código binário:

```
char array[] = { 65, 66, 67, 0 };
char string[] = "ABC";
```

Veja [mostrando como eles se equivalem no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/gyYy3z). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ljbtfcir-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/CharArray.c).

## "Soluções"

Dá para espalhar os *bytes* pelo código e dar a falsa sensação que escondeu alguma coisa. Além de ser complicado, fazer isso é inócuo. Quem sabe descobrirá o que tem ali.

A regra básica é que não pode colocar nada que precisa ficar protegido dentro do executável. Compilar não protege nada. Se o executável está na mão de alguém nada pode ser feito para proteger a informação.

Até dá para criar a *string* criptografada, seria o melhor caminho, ainda que possivelmente questionável. Claro que precisaria analisar o contexto.

O [SO tem uma resposta com criptografia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1360175/221800). Obviamente tem técnicas mais simples. É possível usar uma [técnica básica de XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher). Já dá uma confundida, mas não protege de verdade.

Nem mesmo criptografia já que em algum momento a descriptografia deverá ser usada para usar a informação. Lembre-se que [informações vindas de um cliente nunca é confiável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13298/101). Não importa se é web ou outra forma.

Comment: Eu tinha me desatentado para a falta da finalização, por isso removi a função que acrescentava isso, não achei que fosse necessário, coisas de iniciante né.

Answer (score 2):

```
void sendPassword(void)
{
   char arr_code[x]; // x: constante a determinar  
   arr_code[0] = 79;
   arr_code[1] = 99;
   // etc

   // usa arr_code

   memset(arr_code, 0, x);
}
```

Deste modo seu "código secreto" não vai ficar assim tão visível em uma breve inspeção visual. Seu código é montado byte a byte no início da função, depois você usa o código para o que for necessário, e antes de sair da função você zera o código.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, apesar de não ser um bom método, é eficaz.