# O scanf() grava string em ponteiro que não tem um tamanho definido?

Tags: c, string, ponteiro, scanf

Estou tentando entender como funcionam as *strings* em C. Notei que mesmo não definindo em qualquer parte do código algum limite para o vetor `TextoUm[]` (que segue no código abaixo), a função `scanf()` consegue gravar uma *string* nesse vetor corretamente. Porém o mesmo êxito não ocorre se, na função `scanf()`, eu substituir o vetor por um ponteiro de `char` (inicializado com uma *string* ou não).

Abaixo está um código mostrando exatamente esses casos do vetor e do ponteiro que citei (apesar de ter lido por aí que "vetor" é um "ponteiro").

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    char TextoUm[]="";
    char *TextoDois="";

    printf ("\n\n\tDigite um nome para \"TextoUm\":\n\n\t");

    scanf ("%s", TextoUm);

    printf ("\n\tO texto digitado foi: %s", TextoUm);

    printf ("\n\n\tDigite um nome para \"TextoDois\":\n\n\t");

    scanf ("%s", TextoDois); /* Aqui ele dá erro */

    printf ("\n\tO texto digitado foi: %s", TextoDois);

return 0;
}
```

Depois de executar esse código no depurador, ele apresentou o seguinte erro:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

Sobre esse erro, na Wikipédia diz que ele se trata de uma tentativa de acessar um endereço inválido ou inexistente, mas isso não me ajudou a entender o motivo desse erro só ocorrer com o ponteiro e não com o vetor.

Então minha pergunta é a do título. O `scanf()` consegue gravar uma *string* num ponteiro de `char`, mesmo que não haja um tamanho limite definido para esse ponteiro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Funcionar X certo

Entenda que C deixa você fazer tudo, e exige que você se responsabilize por tudo. Isso é ao mesmo tempo ponto positivo e negativo da linguagem. Ela é próxima do Assembly. Então só não "funciona" o que não tem jeito de funcionar.

Mas funcionar e estar certo são coisas bem diferentes, eu vivo falando isso e quase ninguém ouve. Em C é ainda mais importante. Tem que saber cada minúcia da linguagem antes de usá-la corretamente. "Ouvi dizer" não funciona bem com C, tem que aprender **o certo**.

## `Scanf()`

Antes de mais nada entenda que `scanf()` é algo útil e que em algumas aplicações ele pode ser usado sem problemas, mas a função não é usada para aplicações mais sérias que precisam de validação. Ou é usada apenas como parte de um algoritmo maior.

Um dos problemas é que você pode digitar qualquer coisa e ela aceita. Tem alguns meios de controlar, mas nem sempre são suficientes, e quase sempre não são usados em exemplos simples. Então é fácil corromper memória porque a função escreve até em local não reservado para a variável, afinal C permite "tudo".

Usá-la demais em exemplo simples pode passar a ideia de que ela é o que será usada em aplicações reais.

## Variáveis declaradas

As duas declarações de variáveis funcionam, mas estão erradas, elas não reservam espaço para o objeto *string*, ou seja, não tem um local na memória disponível para a sequência de caracteres que se pretende armazenar. Você tem apenas um endereço de memória para algum lugar, mas esse lugar não está definido e reservado. Para entender melhor leia [O que são e onde estão a "stack" e "heap"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101).

A primeira declaração deveria reservar espaço para a *string* na *stack*, mas o espaço reservado é 0. Ou precisaria colocar o tamanho a ser reservado nos colchetes, ou teria que colocar uma sequência de caracteres do tamanho desejado (o compilador conta quantos são).

A segunda declaração deveria reservar espaço para a *string* no *heap* (provavelmente), mas isso sequer foi tentado. O correto seria chamar a função `malloc()` que pede memória para o sistema operacional (ou para o sistema interno) e devolve o endereço deste espaço reservado.

O valor do tamanho usado apenas reservará memória, não irá impor qualquer limite para nada em C. Se o seu código tentar escrever fora dessa área reservada, funcionará. Mas te dará um [enorme problema](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115613/101), perdendo dados, travando a aplicação (se tiver sorte) ou abrindo brechas de segurança, já que não é o certo.

Algo assim funciona e é quase certo (ainda não é um código 100% seguro):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char TextoUm[10]; //note a mudança aqui
    char *TextoDois = malloc(10); //note a mudança aqui
    printf("Digite um nome para \"TextoUm\":\n");
    scanf("%s", TextoUm);
    printf("O texto digitado foi: %s", TextoUm);
    printf("\nDigite um nome para \"TextoDois\":\n");
    scanf("%s", TextoDois);
    printf("O texto digitado foi: %s", TextoDois);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/8bPPi6). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/joybadpu-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Console/String.c).

Como no seu código nada havia sido reservado no *heap* ele pegou um endereço equivocado (onde estava o `""`) e esse endereço provocou um erro de memória por não poder escrever nele (é uma área de memória protegida).

Então pode usar ponteiro de `char`, mas tem que inicializar corretamente. O erro não é do `scanf()`, ele é apenas o sintoma de que algo foi feito errado antes.

No *array* de `char` parece que funcionou corretamente, mas só por coincidência e porque é um exercício, se fosse uma aplicação real, seria mais problemático. É um erro pior porque não foi detectado.

## Conclusão

Aproveito pra dizer que [*array* se parece com ponteiro mas não é a mesma coisa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101).

Existem outros pontos sobre o assunto, mas isto não pode virar um tutorial completo. Na verdade já respondi aqui no site sobre tudo isso que está aprendendo. Basta pesquisar ou olhar no meu perfil. Outras pessoas já responderam também. Exemplos:

- [Alocação dinâmica de memória X vetor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120103/101)
- [Diferença entre array de char e ponteiro de char](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/130792/101)
- [O que impede um array de ser inicializado com um tamanho variável em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106719/101)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela excelente resposta. Eu cheguei a pensar que, conforme o primeiro `scanf` gravou a string no vetor, a própria `scanf` definisse/redefinisse automaticamente o tamanho da alocação para a string, com base na quantidade de caracteres que ela recebeu do usuário. Agora vejo que isso não é tão fácil assim :). Nem desconfiava que hackers explorassem esse tal buffer overflow, e que ele é relacionado ao meu problema com `scanf`… muito obrigado novamente.