# Copiar string partindo de determinado caractere

Tags: c, string

Estou desenvolvendo um programa em C, que irá trabalhar com 02 arquivos `.txt`

O primeiro arquivo, é um relatório, que sai direto do sistema, e nele estão informações como código do item, localização e quantidade em estoque, essas informações estão na mesma linha...

O código dos produtos, ocupa no máximo os 14 primeiros caracteres da string, e usei o seguinte código para retirar ele do `.txt`:

```
memcpy( cod, &c[0], 14);
cod[15] = '\0';
```

Porém, na continuação da linha, tenho mais informações que queria alocar em outras variáveis, para passá-las para o segundo arquivo `.txt`, o qual eu usarei como saída para uma impressora Zebra.

Como eu faço para acessar os caracteres da posição 15 em diante, e copiá-los para uma variável?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 8):

Você está no caminho certo. Não começou pegando a posição 0? Como quer pegar da posição 15 em diante, use ela. Como quer que vá até o fim, deve pegar o [`sizeof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof) do texto todo e subtrair os 15 que deseja descartar.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char texto[] = "1234567890abcdefghijklm";
    int posicao = 15;
    int final = sizeof(texto) - posicao;
    char parte[final];
    memcpy(parte, &texto[posicao], final);
    printf("%s", parte);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/UrI6fs). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/loajkhyf-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/Substr.c).

Se a *string* não tiver o tamanho conhecido em tempo de compilação, precisaria usar um [`strlen()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) para descobrir seu tamanho. Ou [`strnlen()` se não puder confiar que a *string* está bem formada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115613/101).

No lugar de `&texto[posicao]` pode usar `texto + posicao` já que `texto` é o endereço da *string*, só precisa somar o número de elemento nele. Na verdade o `[]` é apenas açúcar sintático para essa operação aritmética de ponteiro.

Comment: Vale notar que o "sizeof" só vai funcionar apra strings compiladas junto com o programa, como neste exemplo - nunca para dados entrados pelo usuário, ou lidos de um arquivo, ou mesmo copiadas de ma variável para outra sem tamanho pré-definido.

 Talvez seha melhor usar `strnlen` em código desse tipo - mesmo que neste exemplo funcione - por que permite que o programa seja feito de forma genérica.

Comment: @jsbueno adicionado isso. Obrigado.

Comment: (é 2017 -- vale a pena ensinar "strlen" pras pessoas, como se fosse 1985? Sabe como é...`strnlen` ajuda a prevenir "stack overflow"  :-)

Comment: Não é bem assim, concordo que há casos que precisa tomar cuidado, mas nem sempre, há exageros nesse negócio que `strlen()` não deve ser usada. Depois eu faço um adendo, tenho outras edições pra postar, não quero encavalar tudo. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/larryosterman/2009/06/23/good-news-strlen-isnt-a-banned-api-after-all/

Answer (score 2):

Sugiro o uso de `sscanf`. Exemplo supondo campos de comprimento fixo 14,20,20:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
 char texto[] = "cod 1234567890 Joaquim da Silva    933322232";
 char a[30], b[30],c[30];
 if( sscanf(texto,"%14[^\n]%20[^\n]%[^\n]" ,a,b,c) == 3)
    printf("cod='%s' nome='%s' tel='%s'\n",a,b,c);
 return 0;
}
```

executando dá:

```
cod='cod 1234567890' nome=' Joaquim da Silva   ' tel=' 933322232'
```