# Bug em Array ao passar do tamanho 4

Tags: array, c++, dev-c++

Estou fazendo uma questão que pede o seguinte: [image: Questão]

Então fiz esse algoritmo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int i, j, x=0;
int vetor[x];       

printf ("Digite o tamanho do vetor:\n");
scanf ("%d", &x);

for (i=0; i<x; i++)
{
    printf ("\nDigite o numero de posicao %d do vetor:\n", i);
    scanf ("%d", &vetor[i]);
}

system("cls");

for (i=0; i<x; i++)
{
    for (j=i+1; j<x; j++)
    {
        if (vetor[i] == vetor[j])
            printf ("\nO numero %d se repete\n", vetor[i]);
            break;
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

Mas se eu digitar que o tamanho do vetor (x) é igual a 5 ou maior, quando digito o quinto número o programa finaliza. Alguma ideia de como resolver o problema?
Estou utilizando o Dev-C++ 5.11

Comment: Para mim funcionou certinho no Code::Blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem dois erros subtis no código:

1. ```
   int i, j, x=0;
   int vetor[x];
   ```

   Repare que `vetor` é criado com tamanho `0` pois o `x` é `0` no momento da sua declaração, fazendo com que qualquer acesso a `vetor` resulte em comportamento indefinido. Isso pode ter todo tipo de comportamentos desde um *Segmentation Fault* que parece ser o que indicou, ou até um loop infinito de números de entrada, que foi o que aconteceu na minha maquina. Este loop infinito é regra geral sinal de [*Buffer Overflow*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/115613/o-que-%C3%A9-o-buffer-overflow) escrevendo sobre variáveis locais. Para o caso basta que rescreva por cima do `i` com o valor certo para tornar infinito.

   A correção é mesmo alterar o local onde aloca, para que seja a seguir à leitura de `x`:

   ```
   int i, j, x;

   printf ("Digite o tamanho do vetor:\n");
   scanf ("%d", &x);
   int vetor[x]; // <--- agora aqui
   ```

   Note que tambem removi a inicialização de `x=0` na declaração pois não é necessária, uma vez que a primeira coisa que faz com `x` é atribuir através do `scanf`.
2. ```
   if (vetor[i] == vetor[j])
       printf ("\nO numero %d se repete\n", vetor[i]);
       break;
   ```

   Repare que aqui você enganou-se a si proprio visualmente, indentando o `break` como se estivesse dentro do `if` mas na verdade não está, pois o `if` não tem `{}`. Isso é um erro muito comum e às vezes difícil de ver pois o programa não dá nenhum erro, simplesmente se comporta diferente do que estaríamos à espera. Se quiser jogar pelo seguro meta sempre `{}` mesmo quando tem apenas uma instrução, assim tem a certeza que nunca caí nessas armadilhas.

   Apenas para tornar claro, corrigiria assim:

   ```
   if (vetor[i] == vetor[j]){
       printf ("\nO numero %d se repete\n", vetor[i]);
       break;
   }
   ```

[Veja o código com essas duas correções a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/y0TOfJ)