# Variável recebendo lixo

Tags: c, string, alocação

Considerando esse simples validador de senha em C:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h> 
     
    int main(void)
    {     
    char buff[5];     
    int pass = 0; 
     
    printf("\n Entre com a senha : \n");     
    gets(buff); 
     
    if (strcmp(buff, "1234"))
    {         
        printf ("\n Senha Errada \n");     
    }  
    else   
    {         
        printf ("\n Senha Correta \n");         
        pass = 1;     
    } 
    
    if (pass) /* O usuário acertou a senha, poderá continuar*/ 
    {                
        printf ("\n Acesso Liberado \n");     
    } 
    else
    {         
        printf ("\n Acesso Negado \n");     
    } 
     
    return 0; 
    }
```

Se eu entro com a seguinte senha:

`123456`

a saída é:

```
Senha Errada
Acesso Liberado
```

Por que o acesso está sendo liberado se a senha está errada?

Eu sei que da forma que o código está escrito, a string `123456` estoura o vetor impedindo o funcionamento correto da função `strcmp()` por causa da ausência do `'\0'`, mas se o programa imprime `Senha Errada`, quer dizer também que `pass = 0` e o acesso negado, não?

Fiz o *debug* no CodeBlocks, por algum motivo, quando coloco a senha `123456` a variável `pass` é preenchida por lixo, neste caso `54`.
Minha dúvida é: por que ao estourar o vetor `buff` a variável `pass` é afetada?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sua dúvida é referente a: por que ocorre o preenchimento da variável `pass` ao passar o índice máximo de `buff`.

Estas duas variáveis estão na stack. Elas são armazenadas em ordem, seguindo o sistema de FILO (First In, Last out).

Imagine que na memória está organizado da seguinte forma (desculpe a qualidade da imagem :():

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como o índice é baseado em zero, temos os índices disponíveis de 0~4, sendo que o 4° deveria ser para o `\0`.

Quando você passa do índice, você está escrevendo em memória que não pertence ao seu `buffer`. No seu caso, como a imagem acima descreve, pass vem logo depois (em ordem de memória). Isto pode ocasionar problemas bem mais sérios. Imagine se fosse um ponteiro ali? Provavelmente o valor apontado ficaria um valor inválido, e quando tentasse acessar, ocasionaria `Access Violation`.

Desta forma, quando você digitou 123456, a organização na memória ficou a seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Perceba que o valor "6" está na posição do primeiro byte de `pass`. O que contém ali, na verdade, é um código ASCII que representa o 6.

De acordo com a tabela ASCII:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O valor que representa o 6 é 54 em DEC.

E é por isto que você vê o 54 em `pass`

Comment: Entendi. Mas no caso de eu entrar com a senha `12345`. O `pass` vai guardar o `\0`? Fiz aqui e depurei, a comparação deu falsa, como esperado. E `pass` continuou com o valor `0` normalmente.

Comment: Sim, você sobrescreveu a memória com \0. Por um acaso acabou sendo o resultado esperado, mas nunca se pode confiar nisso

Answer (score 4):

Depois de analisar melhor a pergunta, o problema realmente era outro. De fato o `if` estava certo, mas como estava feito da forma ilegível que eu cito abaixo eu acabei me confundindo, vou deixar porque pode ajudar muita gente, já vi fazerem isto.

Não existe problema algum com o terminador, não a ausência indicada. Existe sim o uso de algo que é considerado obsoleto há muito tempo por ser inseguro (`gets()`), veja [Como ler do stdin em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42981/101) (também ajuda). Se usar uma função segura, da forma segura isto não acontecerá porque haverá uma limitação e não estourará memória ocupando espaço de algo que é importante para a plicação manter a informação.

Mais informação sobre o estouro em [O que é o buffer overflow?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115613/101).

---

A documentação de [`strcmp()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) diz que volta 0 para quando a comparação é igual e 1 ou -1 se é diferente. Um `if` espera um `true` para entrar no bloco a seguir e `false` para evitar o bloco do `if` e sair sem fazer nada ou para entrar no `else` quando houver, que é o caso.

C é uma linguagem de tipagem fraca então ela faz coerções de tipos implícitas sob certas regras. Por exemplo tipos numéricos poder virar booleano, até porque originalmente os booleanos nem existiam em C e o número era e é usado para isto. Então o 0 é como se fosse um `false`, e qualquer outro número é `true`.

Comparando agora:

```
strcmp()               if
    0 => igual             0 => false
não 0 => diferente     não 0 => true
```

Então se a função indicar que as *strings* são iguais dá `false` e se elas forem diferentes dá `true`.

Portanto você tem que fazer:

```
!strcmp(buff, "1234")
```

ou

```
strcmp(buff, "1234") == 0
```

para deixar mais claro e evitar certos problemas em alguns cenários.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/Comparing2.c).

O primeiro inverte o valor booleano e o segundo comprar contra o número que espera que seja verdadeiro. Outra forma é inverter o código do bloco do `if` e do `else`, mas costuma ficar mais confuso.

Comment: Boa tarde, Maniero. Minha dúvida não se trata do uso do strcmp em si. Acredito que usei ele de forma correta. O problema é quando eu coloco uma string maior do que o vetor suporta ele está alterando a váriável pass.  Fiz o debug no codeblocks, por algum motivo, quando coloco a senha "123456" a variável pass é preenchida por lixo, neste caso "54". Minha dúvida é: por que ao estourar o vetor buff a variável pass é afetada?

Comment: Editei para colocar um link, este é outro problema, eu só percebi agora porque a forma menos legível me enganou.

Comment: Em relação à ilegibilidade. Você se refere à pergunta, o código, ou ambos? Editei um pouco depois de ler alguns guias aqui no SO, tentei deixar mais legível. Obrigado pelo toque.

Comment: @GustavoOliveira ao código, você faz a execução de forma não intuitiva, porque o mais comum é você procurar fazer o que é verdadeiro antes. A pergunta está ok.